# Finding the monotonicity and bound of a series

Tags: calculus

How would you find the bound  of the following.

$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$

I did
$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$>$\frac{\sqrt{n+1+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

$\sqrt{2}>\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$ making it decreasing

Then I figured bound above by $\sqrt{2}$ and bound below by 1.

But would I be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt n}=\sqrt{\frac{n+1}n}\le\sqrt2$$

since we know (I hope...) that

$$\frac{n+1}n\le 2$$

Comment: Yes yes it is true if n=1

Comment: I don't get it: what is that is "true"?

Comment: Never mind I made a mistake, what I mean is that if n=1 and then n=2 then n=3 and you keep going then $\frac{n+1}{n}=<2$ will be true making it a decreasing series.

Comment: Well, yes....but can you prove it?

Comment: Hmm I guess with a graph it could be proved

Comment: Also observing that $$\frac{n+1}n\le 2\iff n+1\le 2n\iff n\ge 1\;\ldots$$